# Use JUnit 5 parallel test execution and still profit from Spring's context caching?

Tags: spring, junit, junit5, spring-test, spring-context

I am using Spring and [JUnit 5](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/).

[In Spring tests, created contexts are cached](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-caching) so that they don't need to be re-created for each test.

However, according to the Spring documentation, this caching does *not* work when tests are executed in parallel:

> **Test suites and forked processes**
> The Spring TestContext framework
> stores application contexts in a static cache. This means that the
> context is literally stored in a static variable. In other words, if
> tests run in separate processes, the static cache is cleared between
> each test execution, which effectively disables the caching mechanism.

Is there a way, in which one can use [JUnit 5's parallel test execution](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parallel-execution) and still profit from Spring's context caching? Is there a parallel execution configuration that still works with Spring's context caching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that JUnit 5's parallel test execution works without problems with Spring's test context caching.

[For parallel test execution, JUnit 5 seems to use a `ForkJoinPool` under the hood](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parallel-execution-config). Multiple threads can access the [statically cached Spring test contexts](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-caching) without a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use JUnit Jupiter's (JUnit 5's) support for parallel test execution with Spring's integration testing support.

The main thing you'll want to avoid, however, is the use of `@DirtiesContext`, `@MockBean`, or `@SpyBean`.

Details can be found in [Parallel Test Execution](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-parallel-test-execution) section of the Spring Framework reference manual.